# Размер колонки th соответсвенно тексту

Tags: html, bootstrap

Использую Bootstrap. Есть таблица с большим числом колонок в которой отображается статистика:

```
 <table class="table table-bordered">
      <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Keyword</th>
            <th>AdWords top</th>
            <th>AdWords right</th>
            <th>AdWords total</th>
            <th>URLs of top AdWords</th>
            <th>URLs of right AdWords</th>
            <th>Non-Adwords results</th>
            <th>Non-Adwords urls</th>
            <th>Total links on page</th>
            <th>Total SERP results</th>
            <th>Cached SERP</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody> 
      ....
```

Вот как выглядит конечный результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Текст в заголовках таблицы переносится на новые строки, нужно что бы текст в заголовках занимал ровно столько сколько нужно в соответствии с его размером и был выравнен по центру.

Внимание вопрос, как это сделать? :)

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

Вам следует воспользоваться свойством white-space. Оно позволяет организовать роботу с пробелами между словами. В Вашем случае этому свойству следует выставить значение nowrap [подробнее](http://htmlbook.ru/css/white-space)

```
 <table class="table table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <tr class="withoutTransfer">
        <th>Keyword</th>
        <th>AdWords top</th>
        <th>AdWords right</th>
        <th>AdWords total</th>
        <th>URLs of top AdWords</th>
        <th>URLs of right AdWords</th>
        <th>Non-Adwords results</th>
        <th>Non-Adwords urls</th>
        <th>Total links on page</th>
        <th>Total SERP results</th>
        <th>Cached SERP</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody> 
  ....
```

В css

```
.withoutTransfer{
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, помогло!